# Where did all my start menu entries go?

Tags: windows, shortcuts, windows-10-v1703

I recently updated my Windows 10 system to build 15063.483. Windows Update says that this was a "feature update to Windows 10, version 1703."

After the update, all of the shortcuts pinned to my start menu or taskbar and almost all of the programs in the start menu have disappeared. They seem to no longer be indexed either because they don't appear in search results.

The only shortcuts that are still there are Adobe Experience Design CC (Beta) and Sway.

I can confirm that all the shortcuts are still present in:

- `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs`
- `%appdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs`

You can see a `dir` of the first directory here: https://pastebin.com/ydWAcfrg

I have of course rebooted and done the usual checks like `sfc /scannow` and the like.

Why won't the shortcuts appear in the start menu?

---

**Edit:** Here is a simple screenshot of the start menu: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HJdAX.jpg

Comment: May be those deleted by updating process. The path that you've mentioned, stores shortcuts for start menu items not for the pinned ones.

Comment: What exactly is deleted by the updating process? I was indeed referring to start menu items and *not* pinned ones.

Comment: So then recreate search index and thumbnail cache by deleting the previous ones.

Comment: @Biswa On your suggestion I moved `Start Menu\Programs` out of `Start Menu`, rebooted, and had no luck. I then moved them back, rebooted, also to no avail.

Comment: @Biswa I've added a small screenshot of the start menu that will hopefully help illustrate. It's not that the icons are blank; it's that they are not there at all.